# Move method call in to constructor with ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper

It's really useful to be able to refactor using only automated tools, when dealing with legacy code and poor test coverage. Here's one situation I am stuck on.

Given:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
```

Is there a way, using only ReSharper automated refactorings, to move the `Bar()` call in to the constructor of `Foo`?

---

The analogous situation in conventional methods is easy. Given:

```
foo.Bar();
foo.Baz();
```

1. Select both lines
2. Extract Method `Bar2`
3. Inline Method on the call to `Bar()`
4. Rename `Bar2` to `Bar`.

Comment: Probably you shouldn't be able to change the method because this changes will affect every call of first call even then you don't need it, but for a specific places you can create a new method and call it.